# What is the checklist for up-to-date SSL/TLS on OS/X (Snow Leopard)

Tags: macos, https, openssl, pip, osx-snow-leopard

I want my OS/X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) to be running the latest SSL and TLS.  But, now that Apple no longer supports updates of that OS, I am unsure how to proceed.

The problem is that so many things connected with HTTPS seem to break on my system.  (This started a couple years ago and has been worsening.)  I can't see certain websites.  Or I have to add a security exception.  Websites complain my system clock is wrong when it's right.  Now I can't use `pip` with Python at all (this is crippling).

I understand that "openssl libraries" are separate from openssl.  And so I wonder if there are even more libraries -- unknown to me -- that HTTPS uses.  Is there a list of software packages that I should check to make sure there is not some old-ware lying around that is causing my problems?  In other words, I'm hoping for a checklist of packages to check.

I have used the technique in [1] to update my openssl, so that now:

```
$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
```

According to `howsmyssl.com` [2], my system is "good" in all 6 areas that it checks, and my client "is using TLS 1.2, the most modern version of the encryption protocol."  But my problems persist.

I would like to make a diagnosis of what's wrong with my system, and am hoping this could be one way to do it.

Sadly, my hardware limits me to Snow Leopard (10.6) and Lion (10.7).  A fresh Lion install (on top of a fresh Snow Leopard install) did not fix the problem, although I did not do manual updating of openssl.  Maybe I should try that again with the updating...

[1] https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x

[2] https://www.howsmyssl.com/

Comment: Related question appears here: https://superuser.com/questions/1674844/will-squid-fix-ssl-errors-on-old-mac-os-system-snow-leopard